# javascript make form dissapear after submitting

Tags: php, javascript

I have a form on a html page, with a submit button.

```
<div id="tt">
<form method="post" action="time.php">
<input type="text" name="c"><br>
<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="givetime"></FORM>
</div>
```

time.php is just an echo of the current time.

I have ajax code which returns:

```
if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
    document.myForm.tt.innerHTML= ajaxRequest.responseText;
}
```

I don't want to use jquery for this as I want to see if it possible this harder way first...Any idea why this is not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the problem resides in trying to use 'tt' without using getElementById(). The code should be along the lines of

```
if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
  document.getElementById('tt').innerHTML= ajaxRequest.responseText;
}
```

Comment: Can you open it up with Google Chrome's Inspector or Firebug on Firefox and tell me if there's any Javascript errors popping up?

Answer (score 0):

You are not referring to your `div` correctly. Use

```
document.getElementById("tt").innerHTML
```