# A way to make html form disappear?

Tags: php, javascript

What is the recommended or most efficient way (least code/fastest) to make a html form dissapear from a page once the submit button has been pressed and then put in its place the output of a .php file?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/656082/dynamically-hide-form-on-submit

Comment: Don't ask the same question twice. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806009/javascript-make-form-dissapear-after-submitting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Ajax, with JQuery

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Create a div for the response (#response_content), and in the callback of the function do something like

```
$("#form_id").hide();
$("#response_content").html(data);
```

Comment: While this isn't a complete answer it does give the basic idea -- you need to submit the form via AJAX then put the results in the page with javascript if you expect an in-page replacement.

Answer (score 1):

Use JavaScript and set the form to `display:none;` (CSS)

And then add a div layer with your output.

Comment: would this method be able to handle putting the outputted .php text in its place?

Comment: there's no `display:hidden` in CSS. You're looking for `display:none`